# I Can't Sort Bootstrap DataTable by date

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, webforms

I have a bootstrap data table.I have filled the table from the database.My databasw query is finished with "Order By Date Desc" but my data table doesnt sort orderly,it sorts like the picture that i have adde below.What can i do to fix that problem?

[image: Data Table]

Comment: are u sure that the dates are dates and not strings

Comment: In html dates are always a string. So make sure there is a leading zero if you want to sort on that column. Or as @Elvis Jr suggests create a dummy column that has the date in a correct sortable format.

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable and http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/. I think these libraries will help your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable sort by the column you specify (default first column) even if the data is sort. You can use a hidden field of ticks in the date column like this:

```
 <td><span class="hidden">@item.Date.Ticks</span>@item.Date</td>
```